# std::regex_error - Unexpected escape character

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, c++17

Given that this code works

```
std::string pattern = "(\\d+)";
std::regex iregex = std::regex(pattern, std::regex_constants::icase);
```

I am getting a error for bellow code

```
std::string pattern = "(\\d+)";
std::regex iregex = std::regex(pattern, std::regex_constants::extended);
```

can someone please explain the difference..??

Comment: please include the full error in the question

Comment: Unrelated: I suggest that you use raw string literals when building your regular expression.

Comment: The [description here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type), if you follow the [link for `extended`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) shows that `\d` is not part of the `extended` pattern set.

Comment: The default is to use [ECMAScript](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript) regular expressions, which are different from [extended POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) regular expressions.

Comment: From [tag_09_04_02](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_02) *"The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by an unescaped <backslash> ( '\\' ) is undefined"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::regex` can be used with or without flags (the second parameter). 
If there is no flag modifying the grammar: (basic, extended, awk, grep, egrep), it will use by default ECMAScript. 
So flags like (icase, nosubs, optimize, collate) by default use the ECMAScript grammar.

**Now the 2 flags from the question in detail**

From documentation it says that if you use `std::regex_constants::extended` it will

> Use the extended POSIX regular expression grammar [grammar documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04).

And in the grammar documentation it says:

> An ordinary character is an ERE that matches itself. An ordinary
>   character is any character in the supported character set, except for
>   the ERE special characters listed in [ERE Special Characters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_03). The
>   interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by an unescaped
>    ( '\' ) is undefined, except in the context of a bracket
>   expression (see [ERE Bracket Expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_05)).

And as you can see, `\d` is not in the special characters list.

**As for the `std::regex_constants::icase`:**

`std::regex(pattern, std::regex_constants::icase)` is equivalent with `std::regex(pattern, std::regex::ECMAScript | std::regex::icase)`.

And the ECMAScript grammar accepts `\d`, which you have to escape so `\\d`. You can read more about this grammar [here](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10).

#### TL;DR

`std::regex_constants::extended` doesn't know about `\d` and accepts `\\` only between brackets (`[]`).
`std::regex_constants::icase` accepts it because it uses the `std::regex_constants::ECMAScript` grammar.